# Does ActiveMQ support secure websockets?

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

Following a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022486/what-solution-should-i-use-for-this-webapp-with-websockets-activemq) regarding ActiveMQ and WebSockets, I would like to know if secure WebSockets are supported.

I can't find anything about them on the official website (OT: the documentation is really badly organized) and I tried with the following transport connectors without any success:

```
<transportConnector name="websocket" uri="wss://0.0.0.0:61614"/>
<transportConnector name="websocket" uri="ws+ssl://0.0.0.0:61614"/>
```

It seems strange to me that such a connection is really not possible given the professional target of ActiveMQ and the fact that other transport support ssl (E.g. stomp+ssl).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time...

ActiveMQ supports only websocket  ws:// urls

[Apollo 1.1 SNAPSHOT](http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/download.html) supports both ws and wss

[For example:](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Apollo-and-websockets-td4200336.html#a4346918)

```
 <connector id="ws" bind="ws://0.0.0.0:61623" connection_limit="2000"/>
 <connector id="wss" bind="wss://0.0.0.0:61624" connection_limit="2000"/>
```

Comment: I didn't know about Apollo, seems great!

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer: Yes, as of 5.7.0: http://activemq.apache.org/websockets.html

Quoted here:

> Version 5.7.0 introduced Secure Web Socket transport. To configure it you need two things. First, you need to configure a new transport connector like this

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="secure_websocket" uri="wss://0.0.0.0:61614"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

> Note that we use wss url prefix to denote a secured version of the protocol. Next you need to provide SSL context for this transport. You can do that by providing sslContext in your broker configuration in a similar fashion as you'd do for ssl or https transports.

```
<sslContext>
    <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks"
        keyStorePassword="password" trustStore="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ts"
        trustStorePassword="password"
    />
</sslContext>
```

> That's it, your secure websocket transport is ready.

Comment: I'll just add (to save other people's time) that the keystore must be in JKS format (PKCS12 won't work, at least with version 5.11.1), and that one can omit trustStore and trustStorePassword if no trustStore is needed.